# How to exclude files using find

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, find

Unlike the `--exclude` parameter for `rsync` that can excludes both files and directories, the *nix `find` command's `-prune` parameter can only exclude directories.

So how can I exclude a certain type of files (say .bak) when invoking `find`?
In other words, how to make the following non-working example works?

```
find --exclude=*.bak /some/dir
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question properly, the following will work:

```
find /some/dir \! -name '*.bak'
```

Comment: For my case, I'd use `-iname`, just FTA.

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -type f \( ! -iname "*.bak" \)
```